# Ubuntu installer failed while attempting to install in Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, iso-image, virtual-disk

I have created a virtual PC using Virtual Box. This machine has 4096 MB of RAM and a VDI virtual hard drive (dynamically allocated drive space).

I insert into the virtual disk drive the ISO image for Ubuntu 18.04, boot up the virtual PC, click "try Ubuntu", and then run the installer.

Once I get to the point where I click "install now", the installer lasts a few seconds then spits out the following message:

*--------------------------------------------------*

***Installation Failed***

*The installer encountered an error while copying files to the hard disk*

*[Errno 5] input/output error*

*This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.*

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCcQ8.png)

*--------------------------------------------------*

**My question is:** why would this be a disk read problem? There is no physical disk drive involved here, so it couldn't possibly be a faulty disk. How do I trouble shoot this? I'm not quite sure where to start.

After thinking it was a problem with the dynamically allocated VDI, I decided to try again and this time create a partition scheme manually (and put the boot loader on /dev/sda1 rather than /dev/sda) so that the installer wouldn't have to attempt to write to any block of the hard disk that hasn't been dynamically allocated yet. Screenshots of this scheme can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtEg3.png). The purpose of the unallocated space between the partition for root (/) and the partition for swap is so that the dynamically allocated disk file isn't any larger than necessary (I need to be able to back it up). If more space is needed, the first partition can be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the ISO might be broken. 
You can check the ISO MD5 checksum,

Here is a list of the latest Ubuntu desktop image SUMs:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/MD5SUMS

Here is a guide for windows etc:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

I hope this helps,

Comment: Ok, the checksum was one of the first things I thought of, and it was fine. What is the next thing I should check?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, hyper-v was causing the issue and deactivating it in Windows features wasn't enough... (even after restarting).
I had to run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and restart.
See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240518/728292) for detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after installing docker desktop (not toolbox).  This uses WSL2 which in turn uses hyper-v.  The dilemma is that if you turn off hyper-v then WSL2 doesn't work which prevents docker from starting.  But if you leave it enable then docker works, but virtualbox breaks.

Since my use case doesn't use a lot of disk i/o, I was able to do the following workaround:

- disabled hyper-v (both in Windows Features app and from running bcedit command from above)
- reboot windows
- install and update my ubuntu VMs in virtualbox
- re-enable hyper-v
- reboot
- start docker
- start virtualbox VMs

Obviously, this is less than ideal work around. Plus, virtualbox sometimes acts up or doesn't work with hyper-v installed.

Eventually, I got tired of this.  I uninstalled docker desktop and installed docker on my ubuntu VM. Again not ideal, but at least both I can run both docker and vb.